# Reach HTTPS url using wildcard SSL certificate

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, https, wsdl

My web application is trying to reach the WSDL deployed at another server with the URL: https://172.xx.xx.xxx/interface/Webservice?WSDL

In order to do this, I've installed their SSL certificate to the keystore of my application server. However, the SSL certificate of the server I'm connecting to uses a wildcard SSL certificate.

Thus I'm getting the error: HTTPS hostname wrong: should be <172.xx.xx.xxx>

The server I'm connecting to doesn't have any plans to add my desired SAN in their certificates. Is there another way to connect to a wildcard SSL certificate?

Comment: I believe that ssl should be created for FQDN not for IP address. So instead of `https://172...` use `https://hostname`.

Comment: Thank you! This solved our problem, we connected to the DNS instead of the IP address.